# How to understand extension Chrome store statistics

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, statistics, store

These are Chrome extension statistics and I'm trying to understand what are these statistics:

- installs

[image: installs]

- uninstalls

[image: uninstalls]

- impressions

[image: impressions]

- ta da! number of users

[image: total]

I'm watching it around few months. I even wrote to support 2 or 3 times. All they said: "all is fine".
But I just can't understand what are these charts and why in the world I would need it if all it shows is total nonsense.

Here is the problem as I see it: the amount of installs minus amount of uninstalls should be equal to new users by the day, shouldn't it? And we can see that graphs of installs and uninstalls are about to add few hundreds of users, but in total number amount of users is decreasing.

Though it was my point, probably it's nonsense for me, but I'm not getting something important.